# Decode URL in Java

Tags: java, url, decode, urlconnection

I need help decoding a URL found in a class inside a Java Archive (JAR), this might be malicious and want to see where it leads.

```
protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL paramURL)
throws IOException
{
new URLConnection(paramURL)
{
public InputStream getInputStream()
{
return (InputStream)Q5910778.1.this.val$Q53053143.Q8136909(paramURL);
}
```

There is also other classes in the JAR if it's needed.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: And where's the url? And where's the code of the class ``Q53053143`` thats mentioned in your code?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I believe the only way you could see a URL in a decompiled binary JAR would be if it were a constant of some sort, which the code above does not imply.

Comment: @f1sh That class wasn't included in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to trace exactly what site the app is trying to reach. You can set up a dummy proxy server to keep it from actually reaching anywhere if you're truly concerned.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out!